# Internationalization & NLS parameters

Tags: database, oracle

I'm trying to understand internationalization support, charset encoding & conversion in Oracle's products.
Unfortunatelly more I read more confusions come to my head. I hope for Your's help.

Here are my questions:

1.) Could someone explain me step by step how client & server communicates with each other taking into account NLS parameters & charset conversion? I know there are such topics on the net, but that aren't clear enough for me.

2.) If I'm correct that in the case when the server and client are separate machines NLS_LANG have to be set on both separately?

3.) How to set NLS_LANG on server machine? Is it the same way like on the client?

4.) What is the difference in setting NLS_LANG in the registry in Orcale branch, in the system variables (using controll panel) and by "set" command in command line?

5.) How the chasrset conversion is done? I've read somewhere that "If the character set is the same at the client and the server, Oracle directly stores whatever is submitted by the client. No conversion is involved"
So is there comparison like "NLS_LANG on the server machine" vs "NLS_LANG on the client machine" or ratcher "NLS_LANGUAGE on the server machine" vs "NLS_LANG on the client machine"?

6.) What is the case: the server sends it's NLS info (NLS_LANG or NLS_LANGUAGE?) to the client or ratcher clinet sends NLS_LANG settings tp the server?

7.) Where the conversion is done? On the client system or server?

Thanks for all help in advance!:-)

Answer (score 0):

NLS_LANG should be set to the character set of your client application. This is often the character set your operating system uses. For me (Dutch) Windows is using the [Windows 1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) encoding so I set my NLS_LANG on the client to WE8MSWIN1252.

1) Sorry, a step by step explanation would be to long a story and just another topic

2) The server NLS_LANG is *only* used when you run SQL*Plus directly on the server. In that case the server is just like any other client.

3) See 2), most of the time NLS_LANG on the server is irrelevant.

4) I am not sure about the exact precedence but I believe the "SET" command line is strongest. If that is not set the control panel environment variables are used. When those are not present the registry is used and finally, when the registry is empty US7ASCII is used.

5) Comparison is done beteen NLS_LANG on the client and NLS_CHARACTERSET on the server. The latter can be verified with `SELECT VALUE FROM V$NLS_PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET`.

6) See 7, the NLS_CHARACTERSET of the server is sent to the client as well as the other way around.

7) I once read that if the appropriate conversion tables are available on the client, the conversion is done at the client. If not enough information is available the conversion is done at the server.